# "Unpermitted parameter: current_password" when editing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

There are numerous questions (ie: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808571/unpermitted-parameters-current-password-rails-4-devise) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384289/unpermitted-parameters-adding-new-fields-to-devise-in-rails-4-0)) that address this issue (and were useful to others with the same problem), but none of them have worked yet for me.

Using Rails 5.0.0 and Devise 4.2, ultimately I am trying to allow admins to edit other users, and to allow regular users to edit their own accounts. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081744/devise-form-within-a-different-controller) required [a few modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583473/edit-other-user-as-admin-in-devise-ruby-on-rails), since by default Devise doesn't let the logged-in user edit other users.

The form in the `users/:id/edit` view now populates with the correct user, BUT the update fails, with `Unpermitted parameter: current_password` in the logs. I believe that I need to whitelist `:current_password`, but none of the suggestions accomplish this for me.

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}, path_prefix: 'my'
resources :users
```

(The `path_prefix` "my" was suggested as a way to avoid route conflicts between Devise and the `:users` resource.)

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  ...

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :show, :update, :destroy]

  ...

  def edit
  end


  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to cohorts_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :roles, :nickname, :location, :headshot, :goals)

  end
end
```

You might be wondering why I didn't add `:current_password` to the `user_params`. Doing so results in an [unknown attribute 'current_password' for User. error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142374/railstutorial-org-chapter-6-unknown-attribute-password) (Adding the suggested `attr_accessor` didn't help.)

This is the first time I've needed to customize Devise. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you get when you type `User.column_names` in your console?

Comment: => ["id",
 "email",
 "encrypted_password",
 "reset_password_token",
 "reset_password_sent_at",
 "remember_created_at",
 "sign_in_count",
 "current_sign_in_at",
 "last_sign_in_at",
 "current_sign_in_ip",
 "last_sign_in_ip",
 "created_at",
 "updated_at",
 "roles",
 "first_name",
 "last_name",
 "current_cohort",
 "nickname",
 "location",
 "goals",
 "headshot"]   Does current_password need to be a member of that list? I guess I thought it was kind of a "pseudo" parameter.

Comment: @JonathanDueck - No you definitely don't need to include `current_password` in the list. Devise exposes this parameter exclusively for user's account update action.

Comment: Are you sure adding `attr_accessor :current_password` to `user.rb` model didn't solve the problem while having it in the `user_params`?

Comment: It fails silently. the server log shows the PATCH to 'users/1`, it shows the params including "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", the SQL queries (IE: "SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE...", a BEGIN, a ROLLBACK, and it concludes by re-rendering the edit form.

Comment: why don't you use the user_registration method provided by devise to change the password

Comment: @ Othmane Hi. Changing the password isn't a problem. (I was having a problem with the parameter "current_password"), but the problem is with editing the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this. I added [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113248/devise-update-user-without-password) to the update action of my UsersController:

```
if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user[:password_confirmation].blank?
    params[:user].delete(:password)
    params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
end
```

Since it was failing silently, [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060014/how-to-find-the-cause-of-activerecord-rollback) was also helpful in diagnosing the update action:

```
    Rails.logger.info(@your_object.errors.inspect)
```

Thanks all! Pleased to have this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in UsersController ->>> user_params function ->>> in the permit, I think you should add it in permit ...

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :roles, :nickname, :location, :headshot, :goals, :current_password) <<<< THERE

  end
```

Comment: I confirm that I have attr_accessor :current_password in User.rb, and that :current_password has been permitted in user_params in the UsersController. I get BEGIN and ROLLBACK, with no error message to indicate why the update doesn't occur.

Comment: Have you generate devise registration controller with this command? rails generate devise:controllers users

Comment: I wrote the UsersController and RegistrationsController manually. (I hadn't been aware that you can generate Devise controller(s) in the manner you suggest.)

Comment: Yes you can and it is recommended with devise. Because devise's controllers are in a spacename 'users'. Maybe you should add a folder named 'users' in controllers folder, and put your registration controller in him. After that add 'Users::' in registration controller. Like that: 'class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController'

Comment: I implemented this suggestion and the result is unchanged; BEGIN and ROLLBACK without an error message. I have noticed in "pry" that when I look at the params, "permitted:false". But when I look at the user_params, "permitted: true". Since the user_params are what get passed to the update action, and they are supposedly permitted, does that point out a direction for solving this? Maybe an issue with the devise parameter sanitizer? Not sure at this point.

Comment: Did you add the 'simple' users_controller just for redirect to cohorts_path?